# Accredited Certification - past tense

Tags: past-tense

Certified is the past tense of certify, associated with the noun Certification.
What would the past tense associated with Accredited Certification be?

'Accredited Certified' seems wrong.

'Certified by an Accredited Body' works, but is clunky. Is there a better way of changing it to have a past reference?

Comment: "(Holding a) valid Accredited Certification" could work. "Accredited Certification" as a set phrase cannot be modified. HTH.

Comment: Isn't it redundant to say that a certification is accredited? *Accredited* and *certified* are synonyms.

Comment: The distinction between being certified by anyone, and being certified by an accredited body can be (and is for us) an important one.

Comment: An organisation that provides certificates can get accredited. That organisation can then give accredited certification, which could be anything from certificates of education for individuals to corporate certificates for environmental management systems. However, you don't have to be accredited to give out certificates, for example: children getting sports day certificates - and many kinds of corporate certificates. This kind of certificate is not accredited certification.

Comment: I understand the distinction you're making, but I still think it's redundant because in most situations the difference is understood from context. If someone says they're a "certified accountant", for example, or that they have a first aid certification, it is understood that the certification comes from an appropriate authorising body and not from a random neighbour with a printer.  Alternatively in my experience the term accreditation is used on its own rather than accredited certification. Nobody describes a kid with a sports day certificate as having been certified.